# training result changes of each run in TensorFlow official example

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am running the example of "MNIST For ML Beginners" (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners). The official code is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py

Then I found the results are different if I ran it multiple times. The question is how can this happen if there is no randomization  in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the source code here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#181, it is actually the training examples changing every time.

For your convenience:

```
numpy.random.shuffle(perm0)
```